# Fix a typo in [andriod-compose-stack] tag name

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Obviously it should be named [android-compose-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-compose-stack).

There is only 1 question, but there are a wiki and an excerpt already present.

Comment: Why not create the new tag, copy the wiki etc and then delete the wrong tag from the question. It will then get roomba'd

Comment: @Paulie_D These changes should be approved by the community then (I mean new wiki an excerpt). Last time I did this with another tag, but it is not approved yet after some time. I think a moderator can fix a typo in 1 minute.

Comment: 20k users can edit tag excerpts without waiting for approval. It might not be possible to fix the typo without mod intervention purely because of the tag similarity check. I'm gonna try and fix it - if I can't, we'll likely need a mod

Comment: ... that being said, the wiki [was plagiarized](https://web.archive.org/web/20200506021436if_/https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/package-summary.html), so I won't be moving that. Also [status-complete]

Comment: @Zoe maybe you know more android, but what's the difference between the compose stack and the jetpack compose tag? Isn't one a subset of the other.

Comment: @Braiam Jetpack is a UI framework, os compose stack is the subset. Probably refers to an element or class, but iDunno. Haven't used Android since before Jetpack was released

Comment: @Braiam Yes, it is a subset. It is a more specific tag

Comment: It's necessary since we have already the level immediately above? We really shouldn't have tag for every function/class of every framework

Comment: This tag should be deleted, already there is `android-jetpack-compose` no need to create a tag for each layout in `jetpack-compose`. The best thing is to just create another tag called `jetpack-compose-layout` which will be used with `android-jetpack-compose` for layout questions

Comment: @PeterHaddad It could be true. Nevertheless, there is [tag:android-layout] tag, but also more specific tags like [tag:android-linearlayout], [tag:android-constraintlayout], etc.